# Sorted over 3 elements in a tuple Python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, sorting

Attempting to sort a tuple that specifies a person's birthday (day, month, year) from youngest to oldest.

So, for example

```
def sort_something(birthday: [(int, int, int)]):
    sorted(birthday, key=lambda int:int[2])
    return birthday
```

However, when I run this, it produces an index range error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    line 68, in <module>
    ('Joyce',(2,21,1920))
    line 20, in sort_ages
    sorted(data, key = lambda int: int[2])
    line 20, in <lambda>
    sorted(data, key = lambda int: int[2])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What language is this, python? Also, if it is python, and that is your date specifier, you should just be able to sort the raw tuples and get the desired result; they will be sorted by day first, then month, then year (might want to reverse the tuple order). Also, please post your *actual code* since that's not valid syntax, and your *actual traceback* so we can see exactly what the problem is; the index error could be completely unrelated.

Comment: Also remember that calling ``sorted(birthday)`` returns a *new copy* of the list that has been sorted, it doesn't perform it in-place. If you want in-place sorting, use ``birthday.sorted(...)``

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple erros in your code:

- `sorted(birthday)` returns a copy. It doesn't modify `birthday`
- `int[2]` should work if each item has `3` numbers (day, month, year)
- don't use `int` as a variable name, it is a builtin name

```py
from datetime import date

def by_date(day_month_year):
    return date(*reversed(day_month_year))

L = [(3, 12, 2059), (13, 3, 1999), (1, 1, 2059)]
print(L)
L.sort(key=by_date)
print(L)
```

#### Output

```py
[(3, 12, 2059), (13, 3, 1999), (1, 1, 2059)]
[(13, 3, 1999), (1, 1, 2059), (3, 12, 2059)]
```